# How do I make this Merge Sort function a generator (Python)?

Tags: python, algorithm

So I understand how to make the merge sort algorithm in Python 3, and this is my code below for implementing the function:

```
def x(arr):
    for i in mergeSort(arr):
        yield from i

def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        middle = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:middle]
        right = arr[middle:]

        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0

        while a < len(left) and b < len(right):
            if left[a] < right[b]:
                arr[c] = left[a]
                a += 1
            else:
                arr[c] = right[b]
                b += 1
            c += 1

        while a < len(left):
            arr[c] = left[a]
            a += 1
            c += 1

        while b < len(right):
            arr[c] = right[b]
            b += 1
            c += 1

for i in mergeSort([6,3,8,7,4,1,2,9,5,0]):
    print(i)
```

The gist of it is that the function returns the array sorted at the end. However, I am trying to build a sorting visualiser, and to do so, **I need to make this function yield the array whenever a change is made** so you can see the bars switch - **so I need to make it a generator**, but all attempts I've made to do so haven't worked. **How could I modify my code to make this function a generator?**

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure generator will provide any improvement in this case. If you wish to have the list sorted then you need to recall `mergeSort` on the whole list anytime you add an element unless you already know where it should be inserted. Or you may build an index instead and read from it after insertion.

Comment: It's a divide-and-conquer algorithm, and it's typically implemented recursively - the implementation you've shown is also recursive. To turn this into a generator, you'll have to reimplement it using an iterative approach.

Comment: Ok, what's the difference between the approach I have taken and an iterative approach, and how do I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you will need to make sure that a deeply recursive execution can actually report about the state of the *whole* list. With your current set up that is not possible, since the recursive function only gets to see a small slice of the array.

So, in order to fix that situation, don't pass slices with the recursive call, but pass start/end indices instead, giving access to the same `arr` to all function execution contexts.

Then you can `yield arr` after each merge. The code that makes the recursive call should use `yield from`.

I adapted your code only to apply the above idea:

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    # arr is a unique list that all levels in the recursion tree can access:

    def mergeSortRec(start, end):  # separate function that can take start/end indices
        if end - start > 1:
            middle = (start + end) // 2

            yield from mergeSortRec(start, middle)  # don't provide slice, but index range
            yield from mergeSortRec(middle, end)
            left = arr[start:middle]
            right  = arr[middle:end]

            a = 0
            b = 0
            c = start

            while a < len(left) and b < len(right):
                if left[a] < right[b]:
                    arr[c] = left[a]
                    a += 1
                else:
                    arr[c] = right[b]
                    b += 1
                c += 1

            while a < len(left):
                arr[c] = left[a]
                a += 1
                c += 1

            while b < len(right):
                arr[c] = right[b]
                b += 1
                c += 1
            
            yield arr

    yield from mergeSortRec(0, len(arr))  # call inner function with start/end arguments

for i in mergeSort([6,3,8,7,4,1,2,9,5,0]):
    print(i)
```

For the example list, the output is the following:

```
[3, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0]
[3, 6, 8, 4, 7, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0]
[3, 6, 4, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 0, 5]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 0, 5, 9]
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 5, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You could decide to yield also the start/end indices, so that the consumer of the iterator knows where exactly the algorithm was manipulating the list. So then change:

```
        yield arr
```

to:

```
        yield arr, start, end
```

With that change, the output becomes:

```
([3, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0], 0, 2)
([3, 6, 8, 4, 7, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0], 3, 5)
([3, 6, 4, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0], 2, 5)
([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0], 0, 5)
([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 5, 0], 5, 7)
([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 9, 0, 5], 8, 10)
([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 0, 5, 9], 7, 10)
([3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 5, 9], 5, 10)
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 0, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the answer I was looking for. It yields the array each time a change is made, and works perfectly within my sorting visualiser.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def x(arr):
    for i in mergeSort(arr):
        yield i

def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        middle = len(arr) // 2
        left = arr[:middle]
        right = arr[middle:]

        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0

        while a < len(left) and b < len(right):
            if left[a] < right[b]:
                arr[c] = left[a]
                a += 1
            else:
                arr[c] = right[b]
                b += 1
            c += 1

        while a < len(left):
            arr[c] = left[a]
            a += 1
            c += 1

        while b < len(right):
            arr[c] = right[b]
            b += 1
            c += 1
        return arr

# Entry point
generator = x([6,3,8,7,4,1,2,9,5,0])
print(next(generator)) # prints 0
print(next(generator)) # prints 1

# print the remaining elements
for i in generator:
  print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Note that a shorter recursive implementation of merge sort you could use could be the following:

```
def merge_sort(mylist):
    if len(mylist) < 2:
      return mylist

    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []
    
    n = int(len(mylist)/2)
    pivot = mylist[n]

    for x in mylist:
      if x < pivot:
          less.append(x)
      elif x == pivot:
          equal.append(x)
      elif x > pivot:
          greater.append(x)

    return merge_sort(less) + equal + merge_sort(greater)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the shorter recursive approach, I'll try that, but just to clarify, I asked for a generator that yields the full array after every change the merge sort algorithm makes, so if the array was [3,1,2,4], the function would yield [1,3,2,4], then [1,2,3,4], if that makes sense. That way, I can take each of the arrays and use them to change the bars in my sorting visualiser in real time to accurately represent how the merge sort algorithm works.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. In that case maybe start with a global list variable which would get appended to with the array you're sorting every time there is a change to it in your merge sort function. At the end you can see the sorting steps in that variable. It's not ideal, and you'd have to convert that into a generator at the end, but it could lead you to a better solution.